# django re_path() function pattern wouldnt match a url that contains the pattern

Tags: django

I am trying to map any url that ends with patternA to my index function in django. To do this, I have the following in my main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'patternA/$', views.index),
    

    
]
```

When I put http://localhost:8000/patternA/, everything works fine, but things get weird when I put anything before patternA, like: http://localhost:8000/something/patternA/. Although my second path matches the regex *patternA/$*, when putting it inside browser search bar, I get 404 error.
And when I change the pattern to *.*patternA/$*, everything works fine.
Why do I get 404 with *patternA/$* pattern?

I put http://localhost:8000/something/patternA/ in browser search bar, expected to get index function executed but got 404 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `patternA/$` only matches URLs that end exactly with `patternA/`. To match any URL that ends with `patternA/` you need to use the pattern `.*patternA/$`

Comment: Im confused, doesnt the path   http://localhost:8000/something/patternA/  ends exactly with patternA/ ?

Comment: yeah `localhost:8000/something/patternA` does end with `patternA/`. But the regular expression pattern `patternA/$` does not account for anything that comes before `patternA/` in the URL. It only matches URLs that only consist of `patternA/`.

Comment: the django doc at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/ says: Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL; my pattern matches the url, why should I use the .* in the begining of the pattern?  the only difference Using  .* in the begigng of the pattern make is that pattern matches the whole url instead of the patternA/ part.

Comment: The pattern `patternA/$` will only match URLs that end with `patternA/` and nothing else before it. When you use `.*` at the beginning of the pattern, like `.*patternA/$`, it means "match any character zero or more times, followed by 'patternA/'."` This lets the pattern match URLs that have anything before `patternA/` like `something/patternA/.`


Without the `.*`, the pattern `patternA/$` is looking for URLs that consist solely of `patternA/.` It doesn't account for anything that might come before `patternA/` in the URL, so it won't match `something/patternA/.`

Comment: Oh! So you have to match all of the url with your pattern and matching a portion of the url is not gonna be sufficient. If thats the case though, why does the patern: patternA/ ,(my previous pattern but without $) matches urls like: http://localhost:8000/A/patternA/B ? I mean I didnt account for anything that comes before and after the patternA/ , but it still works.

Comment: because without the `$` the pattern will match any url that has `patternA/` in it. The wildcard `.*` accounts for anything before `/patternA/`